# Isuee with concurrent ant calls to DITA OT

Tags: java, dita-ot

We have a multi-thread application, and an integration with DITA-OT throught ant which is called from java.
We are started to face an issue with multiple concurrent ant calls to DITA-OT to run transformations, so when two threads or more run the ant call from java to DITA-OT, it randomly starts to generate an error reading the build_preprocess file.

It seems at the same time when one thread is trying to read the build_preprocess, another thread is deleting it; the build_preprocess is generated in the folder DITA-OT\plugins\org.dita.base

Is there a way to fix the issue, o have DITA-OT to support concurrent requests to run transformations?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgnfq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem:

```
  Failed to read job file: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

might occur if the same temporary files folder is used by two parallel processes.

So just make sure the "dita.temp.dir" and "output.dir" parameters are set to distinct values for the parallel processes so they do not use the same temporary files folder or output folder.

https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/parameters/parameters-base.html#ariaid-title1